# what after extracting my DATA?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Actually, I have a project to deal with. I'm Asking for help. 
My project is in the field of Business intelligence and creating datawarehouses. 
I extracted Data that I need (ETL) and then what should I do ?
I am working with MS SQL Server 2014. 
How to create my dimensions and my Fact table?
looking for advises 
Please do accept my salvation.

Comment: Transform your data into star schema, use Power BI as the dashboard ;)

Comment: to create a star schema, do I need to build dimensions and fact tables using the package that I have build? is that so? how can I do it ?

Comment: I wouldn't go into it without a decent understanding of the topic. You've done the E of the ETL, now you need to do the T and L. So you need to design your facts and dimensions first (see Kimball's books) and then make more ETL that loads your extracted data into those tables. A good starting point would be KImball's book on ETL. It is still relevent despite being old.

Answer (score 3):

This is a big question!  Unfortunately, Stack Overflow's Q&A format isn't the best place to answer this.  But here are few pointers:

- Everything starts with the requirements.  Before you write any code, figure out exactly what your data warehouse will be used for (it can also be helpful to work out what your data warehouse will not be used for).
- Analyse the raw data.  Make sure you know what is and is not available.  Be aware of the source systems shortcomings.  Example: If your reports need to split your customers by country, is this data available?  If so, is it consistently populated (some records have *US*, others *USA*, others still *America*)?   Make a plan for dealing with these issues (see data cleansing below).
- Prototype your data model.  Excel and [Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) are great places to test the design.  Once you start using a database it becomes much harder to change.  Get it right at the very beginning and your life will be much easier.
- Pick an ETL tool.  Make sure you understand it, and it plays to the strengths of you and your team.  I like [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services).
- Import the raw data into [staging tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)).  This can help to simplify the analysis phase.
- [Cleanse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing) the data.  In a data warehouse, you have 100% control over every row, column and cell.  Make use of this fact.  Ensure only quality, useful, well-conformed data makes it into your published tables.

Like all projects, planning and administration is the key.  Writing code and building tables comes last.

Here are some resources which should help you:

- [Kimball Group](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/).  Ralph Kimball literally wrote the book on data warehousing (see next tip).  His company's website contains a few hints and tips.
- If you cannot attend a training course, buy a good book.  I'd recommend this [one](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Definitive-Dimensional/dp/1118530802/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1490788145&sr=1-1&keywords=data+warehouse).  It's a big subject.  Blogs and the internet can only teach you so much.
- Download and try out [Adventure Works DW](https://msftisprodsamples.codeplex.com/).  This is a sample data warehouse and ETL package, built by Microsoft.  It demonstrates some the techniques you can use in SSIS.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. it is just my first time to deal with this field !

Comment: This should definitely be ticked as the answer

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you a more specific answer, but it is a big topic.  I hope your project is a successful one!  Good luck.